# Splitting SequenceFile in controlled manner - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

hadoop writes in a `SequenceFile` in in key-value pair(record) format. Consider we have a large unbounded log file. Hadoop will split the file based on block size and save them on multiple data nodes. Is it guaranteed that each key-value pair will reside on a single block? or we may have a case so that key is in one block on node 1 and value(or parts of it) on second block on node 2? If we may have unmeaning-full splits, then what is the solution? sync markers?

Another question is: Does hadoop automatically write sync markers or we should write it manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked this question in hadoop mailing list. They answered:

> Sync markers are written into sequence files already, they are part of
>   the format. This is nothing to worry about - and is simple enough to
>   test and be confident about. The mechanism is same as reading a text
>   file with newlines - the reader will ensure reading off the boundary
>   data in order to complete a record if it has to.

then I asked:

> So if we have a map job analysing only the second block of the log
>   file, it should not transfer any other parts of that from other nodes
>   because that part is stand alone and meaning full split? Am I right?

They answered:

> Yes. Simply put, your records shall never break. We do not read just
>   at the split boundaries, we may extend beyond boundaries until a sync
>   marker is encountered in order to complete a record or series of
>   records. The subsequent mappers will always skip until their first
>   sync marker, and then begin reading - to avoid duplication. This is
>   exactly how text file reading works as well -- only here, it is
>   newlines.